# No module named "FolderName"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using Python in VS code. I am experiencing the error "no module named 'ch6'" when trying to import the functions from one file to another, where the files are located in two different folders.

I have two folders:

1. "ch6" – which contain the file "RandomCharacter.py". This file has the functions I want to import.
2. "ch7" – which contain the file "CountLettersInList.py" trying to import the functions from "RandomCharacter.py".

If I try to import the functions with the code:

```
import ch6.RandomCharacter
```

I get the error: **"No module named 'ch6'"**

If I use the code:

```
import RandomCharacter
```

I get the error: **"No module named 'RandomCharacter'"**

However, if I copy CountLettersInList.py from folder ch7 to folder ch6, the import works just fine with the code:

```
import RandomCharacter
```

So why can't it import the functions successfully when the files are in two different folders?

Comment: Copying `CountLettersInList.py` to folder ch6 allows you to import `RandomCharacter`?  That makes no sense.

Comment: Also, is there really a `.py` at the end of `import RandomCharacter.py`?

Comment: It is the case. It works when copying CountLettersInList.py to ch6. Maybe because the files are then in the same folder?

Comment: does the folders have `__init__.py` file present?

Comment: It wasn't a .py at the end import RandomCharacter.py. That was typo which now have been edited.

Comment: Where is the file in which you are trying to import?

Comment: @Sukhdeep no, `__init__.py` is not present.

Comment: @Nevus The file is in the folder "ch6".

Comment: Try adding  `__init__.py` file and check the code again. It marks directories on disk as Python package directories [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4116384/7919787).

Comment: When importing .py files in the same folder (importing RandomCharacter.py into test.py where RandomCharacter.py and test.py are in ch6 folder) use `import RandomCharacter`. Importing from sibling folder(importing from ch7 into ch6 where ch7 and ch6 both reside in common folder bar) is a bit complex. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)

Comment: @Sukhdeep Adding `__init__.py`. Didn't make much of a difference unfortunately.

Comment: @Nevus Thank you. I got only get it working when I copy the `RandomCharacter.py` file from ch6 to ch7 (so that both files are in the same folder). I didn't know that it would be such a hassle to import functions from another directory, even when both folders resides from the same common folder bar.

Comment: @KishuInu. May i know if you ever reached my answer? Has your question been fixed?

Comment: @MollyWang-MSFT Sorry for late reply. I finally got the code working with the code:
`import sys
sys.path.append('.')
sys.path.append('../ch6')`

The code runs fine, but for whatever reason, I get the error message:
"Import "RandomCharacter" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports) [5, 8]"

Answer (score 0):

The python import system can be annoying. Correct me if I'm wrong in any assumption I make! So what I understand is you're trying to import a `RandomCharacter.py` into a file located `ch7/CountLettersInList.py`?

The reason you can't import `RandomCharacter.py` into `CountLettersInList.py` is because what `CountLettersInList.py` can see is only in `ch7`. It can't even see the folder `ch6`.

Solution:
You have to go up one directory to see `ch6`. In order to do that tack these lines of code into `CountLettersInList.py`:

```py
import sys

sys.path.append("..")
```

This goes up one directory to search for modules!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your assumption is correct. However, I did not get it working with the code 

`import sys

sys.path.append("..")`

I just got the same error.

Comment: is the sys.path.append("..") above the import import ch6 so it looks like 
```sys.path.append("..")  
import ch6 ```

Comment: Yes, it's above `import ch6.RandomCharacter`. I also tried with just `import RandomCharacter`. Still the same error.

Comment: That's really weird, can you try putting  `CountLettersInList.py` in the same directory as `ch6` and `ch7` and temporarily comment out the sys.path.append("..")

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in `CountLettersInList.py`, then you can import successfully.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("./")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the code working when I turned on a setting, and then ran the code below:

```
import sys 
sys.path.append('.') 
sys.path.append('../ch6')
```

The setting that I turned on:
[image: Setting]

The code runs fine, but for whatever reason, I get the error message:

```
Import "RandomCharacter" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports) [5, 8]
```

Screenshot of error message:
[image: Screenshot of error message]

Comment: Please don't use `Post Answer` to ask follow-up questions. If you can't find the answer via [`Linked`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69413897/13138364#h-linked) / [`Related`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69413897/13138364#h-related) / [`Search`](https://stackoverflow.com/search), then use the [`Ask Question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button and include these details (along with a link back to this question if the context would be useful).

Comment: @tdy Sorry about that. I get why it would be better for the community to have one question per thread.